# How to show weights as part of the plot?

Tags: python, nodes, networkx

How do I show the weights as part of the graph?

[image: Plot 1]

```
my_graph = nx.Graph()
edges = nx.read_weighted_edgelist('edges.txt')
nodes = nx.read_adjlist("nodes.txt")
pos = nx.shell_layout(my_graph)
my_graph.add_edges_from(edges.edges())
my_graph.add_nodes_from(nodes)
nx.draw(my_graph, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

I tried another way

```
labels = {e: g.edges[e]['weight'] for e in g.edges}
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(g,pos,edge_labels=labels)
```

But for this case, I get a very cluttered plot.

[image: Plot 2]

How can I get a plot like the first one but with the weights showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pos = nx.spring_layout(my_graph)` instead of `pos = nx.shell_layout(my_graph)`.

The position of your nodes is determined by your layout command.

Comment: To clarify @matho_noob's answer further, the positioning of the nodes is different between the two plots in the poster's question because the first `nx.draw()` command doesn't actually pass `pos`.  Since it isn't specified in that first call, `nx.spring_layout()` is used by default as per the [docs for `nx.draw()`](https://networkx.org/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw.html).

Comment: Thankyou so much! I got it now and it works!